# Webdav won't connect: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: apache-httpd, webdav

I have a small server running Ubuntu 16.04.  It is successfully serving webpages over https.

I want to set up webdav over https on Apache as well.  I had trouble finding a tutorial that explicitly set that up and ended up using info from a couple different ones, so it's quite possible that I've done something contradictory at some point, but I have no idea what it is.

default-ssl-conf looks like this, with all the template comments removed.  I haven't changed any of the settings before the Alias command except to add the DavLockDB directive.

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock/davLock
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin me@me

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            # My Webdav config starts here
            Alias "/webdav" "/var/www/webdav"

            <Directory /var/www/webdav>
                DAV on
                DirectoryIndex disabled
                AuthType Digest
                AuthName "webdav"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
                Require valid-user
            </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

Connecting via cadaver, to either localhost or the fully qualified name, gets the same response:

```
jbhelfrich@arm:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cadaver https://localhost/webdav
Could not access /webdav/ (not WebDAV-enabled?):
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection to `localhost' closed.
```

I've tried it without /webdav as well, and get the same basic response.
/var/www/DavLock and /var/www/webdav are both owned by www-data

/var/logs/apache2/access.log shows

```
::1 - - [10/Aug/2016:20:07:44 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 229 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.1"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2016:20:07:44 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 405 501 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.1"
```

error.log shows nothing relevant, and other_vhosts_access.log is empty.

alias, dav_fs, dav, and dav_lock modules are all enabled.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Lets Encrypt configuration process had created a site specific ssl config that I hadn't noticed.  Copied the above code into that file and everything worked fine.